# Django 1.11.7 - staticfiles_dir issue

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm developing with django first time. I have read what is : `STATIC_ROOT / STATICFILES_DIR / STATIC_URL`, I know what purpose for each of them.

I have a problem which I keep getting 404 on browser trying to get the css files.

## setting.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '%s/online_static/' % (BASE_DIR)

STATICFILES_DIRS = ['%s/bootstrap/' % (PROJECT_DIR),]
```

## index.html

```
<head>
{% load staticfiles %}
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>{% block title%}Default title{% endblock title %}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{% block metadescription%}{% endblock metadescription %}">
<meta name="keywords" content="{% block metakeywords%}{% endblock metakeywords %}">
<meta name="author" content="alme7airbi9357@gmail.com">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="{% static 'css/shop-homepage.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
</head>
```

## what I did

after setting this params I have run the `python manage.py collectstatic`

Note : `DEBUG = False`

Comment: You probably meant `__file__` ?

Comment: Also, do you have a web server setup ?

Comment: You haven't shown where the static files are actually located in your project.

Comment: yes, but lost it when copying

Comment: the static folders is under the project directory. I do call collectstatic and it collects it

Comment: When `Debug=False` Django stop handling static files. You need to setup a web server.

Comment: Let me be more specific. Say `{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}` is not working. Where is the file `bootstrap.min.css` located in your project?

Comment: Okey, all my static files under project_dir.  Base_Dir > manage.py & Project_Dir > staticfiles_dir .  when I do collectstatic it takes it to " Base_dir > staticFiles "

Comment: your right it works when DEBUG=True, so how to do it if DEBUG=False ?

Comment: When `DEBUG = False`, you need to configure your server (e.g. Apache or Nginx) to serve the static files. See the docs on [deploying static files in production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/deployment/).

Answer (score 0):

As per the Django Docs, follow the configuration steps for static : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/